# Appendices of each chapter in latex

Tags: appendices

[image]I have two chapters and I have two appendix (A and B) for each chapter. How can I create it in latex at the end of my thesis?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want, can you describe in more detail?

Comment: Please provide more information about (a) the document class you use and (b) any packages you load that affect the appearance of sectioning headers and the Table of Contents. Please also clarify what you you intend to achieve: the header of your posting states "appendices for each chapter", yet the screenshot shows the appendices being typeset after the end of (both) chapters. Or, do you have two appendices *per chapter*?

Comment: The  `appendix`package, and more specifically its  `subappendices` environment  might perhaps help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would serve as the starting point that uses `appendix` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{xxxxxxx}
\chapter{yyyyyyy}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]